# JavaScript: Transforming events before passing it on to a callback

Tags: javascript, node.js, eventemitter

I am currently implementing a [Bluetooth Library for Node.js](https://github.com/LukasBombach/sblendid/) that has support for `macOS`, `Linux` and `Windows`. To achieve cross platform compatibility I am using native, platform specific code (Objective-C, C++ & C) that use Node.js' `EventEmitter` and will trigger events whenever an asynchronous Bluetooth operation has completed or some other device has triggered an event for some reason.

The data format for these events look very differently and I would like to normalize them so users of my library will get there events in one single format, not matter which platform they are on.

[image]

Of course, I can attach event handlers to the native `EventEmitters`, transform and normalize the data and trigger Events with that normalized data in my own library.

The problem with that is that the users of the library will be able to attach - and - remove events to my library and what that means is that if they attached an event to my library, let's say to "deviceDiscovered" like so:

```js
const myListener = (device) => { /* ... */ };
bluetoothLibrary.on("deviceDiscovered", myListener);
```

My implementation would have to look a little something like this:

```js
class BluetoothLibrary {
  nativeAdapter = getAdapterForCurrentOS();

  on(event, callback) {
    this.nativeAdapter.on(event, (data) => {
      const normalizedData = this.normalize(data)
      callback(normalizedData);
    });
  }

  off(event, callback) {
    this.nativeAdapter.off(event, callback)
  }

  normalize(data) {
    /* ... */
  }
}
```

The problem with this is if someone wants to remove their event listeners again, like so:

```js
const myListener = (device) => { /* ... */ };
bluetoothLibrary.on("deviceDiscovered", myListener);
bluetoothLibrary.off("deviceDiscovered", myListener);
```

Because of my implementation, the listener never really would be removed because I never really attach the reference to the callback that has been passed to me to the native adapter's `EventEmitter`.

I am wondering if there is a way to transform or pipe events through some transformations on the way before passing them on to an event listener.

Comment: Would this work: return the wrapped callback from the `on` so users can use that reference to pass to the `off`?

Comment: Definitely would work, but would not make up for a great API, imho

Comment: What about a local map of the events and wrapped callbacks? Would only work If there was a single callback for each event by name

Comment: That would work, I hoped there was a less messy solution though